# What was on Debbie's list?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, oceans-8

In the Ocean's 8 movie, Debbie Ocean (*Sandra Bullock*) has a list of 15 items. The piece of paper is shown a couple of times in the movie. Once, when Debbie and Lou (*Cate Blanchett*) are sitting in their den, on a table and Lou tries to snatch the list while Debbie swiftly moves it away. Lou says something to the tune of "*you can add him to the list*".

> I guess the **him** in question is Debbie's ex, the guy she is trying to frame for the heist.

The next time we see the list is towards the end of the movie when Debbie scratches off number 14 from the list.

> 14. <strike>Who's Who</strike>

All items preceding the 14th are already crossed out with only the 15th remaining. My guess is these are plays that she may have learnt from Danny or is her heist bucket list of sorts.

**UPDATE:**

The list seems more likely to be a list of cons. Leaving the 15th item unchecked gives the makers an opportunity to suggest that Debbie is not done yet and there might be a sequel to follow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is not complete, as I cannot tell what the items mean, but we can list a few of them at least.

[image]

- 6. More the merrier
- 7. Made in Heaven
- 8. Hallellujah Time
- 9. Spring Break!
- 10. Crack in the Mirror
- 11. Poof!
- 12. Deviled Eggs
- 13. Who's Who?
- 14. Cupid's Delight

Now, we are pretty confident that Debbie didn't go on *Spring Break* after leaving prison. Also playing *Who's Who*, or listening to Queen's *Made in Heaven* seems fairly pointless to have in a bucket list.

I would say these are code-names for cons, similar to the [first movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69012/in-oceans-eleven-are-the-con-names-real).

- *Made in Heaven* is maybe the delicious soup that induces vomiting
- *Hallellujah Time* is the moment when Daphne is on her knees pucking
- *Spring Break* is when Yen and Lou are stealing all the other necklaces
- *Poof!* is the removal of the Toussaint
- *Deviled Eggs* is putting it into a tray to be split in the kitchen.
- *Who's Who* seems to be the final stage of the plan, where the necklace was split between all of them.
- *Cupid's Delight* is probably the framing of the ex.

This is pure conjecture, as I could not find any sources to corroborate any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the names of the cons reference common idioms and sayings that serve to describe the action in vague terms. Made in Heaven is when they set Daphne up with the skeezy gallerist who sent Debbie to prison. “Match made in Heaven”

Who’s who is when they leave the Museum and blend in with the crowd in gowns and the pilfered necklace divided into seven different pieces of jewelry. They blend right into and are indistinguishable from a “who’s who” of celebrities and socialites. That one works on two levels!!